# How can I prevent apt-mirror from downloading ALL packages

Tags: package-management, mirrors, apt-mirror

I'm trying to configure apt-mirror, it's working fine for ubuntu upstreams but when I use it for something like GitLab, it downloads all package versions.

For example, gitlab-ce is 72GB, each version is under 300MB. How can I keep just the latest or even the last 1 or 2 packages, not 459?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

APT Mirror is intended to mirror **the whole repository** from `mirror.list` entries only.

In a few sentences `apt-mirror` works like this:

1. Gets index files from the repository and processes them (the same process as `apt update`).
2. Downloads files from collected index files, if they do not exist locally. The folder structure is preserved in this process (similar to `wget -c -x <url_file_array>`).

For more detailed information about how `apt-mirror` works and for confirming that **it is impossible to partially mirror the repository to get latest versions only**, you can refer to [The Source code of apt-mirror](https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/blob/master/apt-mirror) (Written in Perl).

So, what to do to get latest versions from large repositories?

My temporary workaround for your situation (taking for example, `gitlab-ce` repository for Ubuntu 18.04 - Bionic):

1. Enter the path for mirroring:

   ```
   cd /path/to/mirroring
   ```
2. Backup `sources.list`:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
   ```
3. Open and comment every line in `sources.list`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
4. Add your desired repository(ies) for mirroring:

   4.1. Add this to `sources.list` and exit from the file: `deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ bionic main`

   4.2. Add the GPG:

   ```
   curl -L https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
5. Update index files:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
6. Fetch latest packages url from added repository and write them to file:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install '*' --allow-unauthenticated -y --print-uris | grep -o '\'http.*\' | tr "\'" " " > download-list
   ```
7. Download the urls with folder structure, because of `-c` option, it will not download files that exist:

   ```
   wget -i download-list -c -x
   ```

   Enjoy!!!

   For reverting everything back, just replace the `sources.list` file with old `sources.list.bak` and do:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```